# Charts generator framework from ASP.NET to HTML5

Tags: asp.net, html, charts, server-side

I'm working in an ASP.NET environment and i'm searching a framework (better if it is open source) which generate **INTERACTIVE** charts on server side.  Since i have to publish this project also for mobile, i'm searching something that produces charts in HTML5.

Anyone could give me a suggestion or links about it?

Thank's so much

Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out [Highcharts .Net](http://highcharts.codeplex.com) ([sample website](http://highcharts.paulovich.com.br/)) or [DotnetHighcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com). Both are C# wrappers written around the [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) charting library.

The original library is in javascript, but both these projects are based entirely on C#, and you dont need to write any javascript code to get charts working. Both have sample projects, in case you are interested, although I think Highcharts .Net is more feature-complete if i'm not mistaken..

If you are looking to use MVC, DotnetHighcharts is the way to go, but if you intend to use webforms, Highcharts dot net handles viewstate for the charts so state management is no longer a headache for you..

Answer (score 1):

It's not *exactly* what you are looking for, but might fulfil your requirements.

Have to checked out [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)? Not to be confused with their infographics api or image charts api.

They will generate HTML5 etc dependant on what browser is used.

And can be considered semi-server-side I suppose, it will generate a portion the markup on Google's server side (n.b. not your server side), though I guessing this will depend on what chart is rendered as some charts will probably be mostly client side. However for any interactive chart a certain amount of clientside technology will be used anyway.

So I suppose it depends on if you mean server-side you mean it is essential it runs on your own server. Running on Google's infrastructure does give you the advantages of a CDN etc so it might outway the need of running on your own server.

Comment: No worries, I'd be interested to find out what you uncover, as I'll probably be looking for something similar in the future - I've starred your question :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Syncfusion HTML5 chart control for your requirement. You can create chart with interactive features such as highlight date points, tooltip, exploded pie, etc., in ASP.NET environment . 
Also, The HTML5 chart is using  element for chart rendering. So, it is providing effective Client side interaction to the chart control. Please refer the below online document and sample link for HTML5 chart.

Documentation Link:

http://help.syncfusion.com/User%20Interface/ASP.NET/Chart%20in%20HTML5

Sample Link:

http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/chart/HTML5%20Chart/ChartAdvUserInteraction/HighlightDemo/CS/HighlightDemo.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a commercial tool, I highly recommend [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). We are using it in our commercial application. The pricing model is good--we evaluated it against FusionCharts--and it is very feature-rich, interactive.

Although commercial, you can use Highcharts under a CC license for everything except for-profit commercial apps.

Answer (score 0):

its old link, But Amcharts are good option too. i used with webform and mvc applications and worked great for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shield UI HTML5 chart library, that will suit your requirement. I have tried it in ASP.NET environment and performs pretty well. For some examples please refer hereL https://demos.shieldui.com/aspnet/aspnet-chart/drill-down

Comment: While this link may assist in your answer to the question, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)